# ModX Evo 301 redirects causing redirect loops

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, modx, modx-evolution

I have been adding 301 redirects to my `.htaccess` file and am having a weird issue where some of them cause a redirection loop (if accessed by any means).

I've noticed this seems to occur if part of the original URL is in the new URL

For example:

`RewriteRule ^massey-fergus http://allclass.com.au/massey-ferguson-tractors.html [R=301,L]`

Would anyone know whats going on and how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason is because `^massey-fergus` matches your target: `/massey-ferguson-tractors.html`. Did you mean to not match against the end of the URI?

```
RewriteRule ^massey-fergus$ http://allclass.com.au/massey-ferguson-tractors.html [R=301,L]
```

The `$` at the end of the regex pattern makes it so it *only* matches the URI `/massey-fergus`.